# Объединение методов в один параметризованный

Tags: java

Есть 2 метода (для сортировки собак и кошек):

```
public static Cat[] sort(Cat[] array) {
    Cat[] mass = array;
    Cat buffer = null;
    Cat current = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
        current = mass[i];
        for (int j = i; j < mass.length; j++) {
            if (current.compareTo(mass[j]) == 1) {
                buffer = current;
                current = mass[j];
                mass[j] = buffer;
            }
        }
    }
    return mass;
}

public static Dog[] sort1(Dog[] array) {
    Dog[] mass = array;
    Dog buffer = null;
    Dog current = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
        current = mass[i];
        for (int j = i; j < mass.length; j++) {
            if (current.compareTo(mass[j]) == 1) {
                buffer = current;
                current = mass[j];
                mass[j] = buffer;
            }
        }
    }
    return mass;
}
```

Как их объединить в один параметризованный метод?

Comment: Кошки и собаки имеют общего предка? Или общий интерфейс?

Comment: нет, не имеют...

Comment: Тогда это невозможно

Comment: Учитывая, что у них у обоих есть метод `compareTo` - скорее всего оба класса имплементируют интерфейс `Comparable` и тогда всё возможно)

Comment: @АндрейПетров а вы в этом уверены? Метод `compareTo` есть в обоих классах - есть подозрение, что они оба реализуют интерфейс `Comparable`, чего будет достаточно для сортировки. Хотя, конечно, `compareTo > 1` не очень вяжется со стандартной реализацией этого метода.

Comment: Да, реализуют интерфейс Comparable, я думал спросили про другое.

Comment: @Regent Пардон, там == 1

Answer (score 3):

При использовании `<T extends Comparable<T>>` получается так:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort1(T[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        T current = array[i];
        for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++)
        {
            if (current.compareTo(array[j]) == 1)
            {
                T buffer = current;
                current = array[j];
                array[j] = buffer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Сам алгоритм сортировки я не проверил (есть подозрение, что такой вариант работает некорректно), поправил лишь некоторые моменты:

1. `Dog[] mass = array` не создаёт новый массив, поэтому нет смысла ни использовать `mass` вместо `array`, ни возвращать его (всё равно `array` будет изменён)
2. Объединил объявление и инициализацию переменных

Comment: Только не `<T extends Comparable>`, а `<T implements Comparable>`

Comment: @Barmaley для generics [есть только](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) `extends`